# Is there a way to set a global variable to be used with aiortc?

Tags: python-3.x, aiortc

I'm trying to have a python RTC client use a global variable so that I can reuse it for multiple functions.

I'm using this for a RTC project I¨ve been working on, I have a functioning js Client, but the functions work differently from python. 
The functions on the server and js client side are my own, and do not have have parameters, and I hope to avoid having to use them on the python client I'm making.

I've been using the aiortc Cli.py from their github as a basis for how my python clien should work. But I don't run it asynchronous, because I am trying to learn and control when events happen. 
the source code can be found here, I am referring to the codes in line 71-72
https://github.com/aiortc/aiortc/blob/master/examples/datachannel-cli/cli.py

this is the code I'm trying to run properly

> I've only inserted the code relevant to my current issue

```
import argparse
import asyncio
import logging
import time

from aiortc import RTCIceCandidate, RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription
from aiortc.contrib.signaling import add_signaling_arguments, create_signaling

pc = None
channel = None

def createRTCPeer():
    print("starting RTC Peer")
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    print("created Peer", pc)
    return pc

def pythonCreateDataChannel():
    print("creating datachannel")
    channel = pc.CreateDataChannel("chat")
```

the createRTCPeer function works as intended, with it creating an RTC Object, but my pythonCreateDataChannel reports an error, if I have it set to "None" before using it

> AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'CreateDataChannel'

and it will report

> NameError: name 'channel' is not defined

same goes for pc if I don't set it in the global scope before hand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this:

```
import argparse
import asyncio
import logging
import time

from aiortc import RTCIceCandidate, RTCPeerConnection, RTCSessionDescription
from aiortc.contrib.signaling import add_signaling_arguments, create_signaling

pc = None
channel = None

def createRTCPeer():
    print("starting RTC Peer")
    global pc
    pc = RTCPeerConnection()
    print("created Peer", pc)

def pythonCreateDataChannel():
    print("creating datachannel")
    global channel
    channel = pc.CreateDataChannel("chat")
```